# Xamarin Forms Messaging Center Not Working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to C# and Xamarin Forms and am trying to implement Messaging Center in my project. I am trying to push a modal page and then send data from the modal back to the original page. However, it isn't quite working as I expected.

Here is the code from the main page:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Info, string[]>(this, "nameUpdate", (sender2, name) =>
        {
            dataName.Text = name[0];
        });

await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Info(dataName.Text));

MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Info, string[]>(this, "nameUpdate");
```

And here is the code to execute when a button is pressed on the modal page, where message is a string[]:

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
MessagingCenter.Send<Info, string[]>(this, "nameUpdate", message);
```

MyPage is the name of the original page, and Info is the name of the page that is being called as a modal. I am not getting any errors, just the statements in the subscribe block are not executing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `unsubscribe` and swap the order of these two:

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
MessagingCenter.Send<Info, string[]>(this, "nameUpdate", message);
```

It seems the `unsubscribe` happens before the `send`.